# Cannot populate an array from JSON object in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have the following JSON object:

```
Object { JP: "JAPAN", PAK: "PAKISTAN", IND: "INDIA", AUS: "AUSTRALIA" }
```

This JSON is a response data returned from a get `call(HttpClient Angular)`.

So now, I need to populate this into the following to display as a dropdown list.

`countryList: { countryCode: string; countryName :string }[];`

I tried doing the following :

```
for (const key in resData) {
  if (resData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     var obj ={
       countryCode :key,
       countryName : resData[key]
      }
    this.countryList.push(obj);
  }
}
```

But when I execute I'm getting this error

```
"_this.countryList.push is not a function"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you’ve posted only defines the type of countryList. You need to also initialise it as an empty array before you can push to it - see below.

```
countryList: { countryCode: string;countryName :string }[] = [];
```

Comment: Yes, have done so. Could you suggest me a way to close this thread?

Comment: Thanks! Everything on the site just stays up. That way if someone has a similar issue, hopefully your question will help them too.

Comment: Okay. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `entries` from the object and then `map` it to the array of objects:

```
Object.entries(countries).map(([key, value]) => ({
     countryCode: key,
     countryName: value
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare **countryList** as list.

```js
var resData={ JP: "JAPAN", PAK: "PAKISTAN", IND: "INDIA", AUS: "AUSTRALIA" };
countryList=[];
for (const key in resData) {
  if (resData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     var obj ={
       countryCode :key,
       countryName : resData[key]
      }
    countryList.push(obj);
  }
}
console.log(countryList)
```